# create a collection with an index

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I want to create a collection which has a unique index.
I *used* to think that it's enough to do this in my application startup-

```
db.collection('myCollection', {strict: true}, function (err, collection) {
    if (!err)
    {
        collection.ensureIndex({ "name" : 1},{unique: true}, function dummy(result,err){});
    }
});
```

``

however, when the application is first run, the 'myCollection' collection doesn't exist, so my 'ensureIndex' isn't called (an error is returned to the callback). that means that my index isn't being created as expected.

I saw that you can use `createCollection()` function, but as I understand it's not standard practice.
What's the best practice to ensure that, when the very first document is inserted, my index is already in place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `{strict: true}` option from your [`db.collection`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/db.html#collection) call; that's what's causing it to return an error to your callback for the case where the collection does not exist (that's the sole purpose of the option).

```
db.collection('myCollection', function (err, collection) {
    if (!err)
    {
        collection.ensureIndex({"name": 1},
                               {unique: true}, 
                               function dummy(result,err){});
    }
});
```